# How can I revert my changes using 'git pull'?

Tags: git

I did a 'git pull' instead of a 'git pull --rebase'.

```
SHA: 138937298d80a7c84d0630b1db509ca2596aca91  // top of my git

<< some changes I got from 'git pull' >>
SHA:

SHA:
<< end of some changes I got from 'git pull' >>

SHA: 08ebb55902e206a30d6f344b4684bd525970dda3  // my original top of my git before i do anything.
```

My question is how can I revert the changes I got from 'git pull' and then I do a 'git pull --rebase' ?

Another question is I am using 'gitx' on Mac, the changes I got from 'git pull' are on a different vertical line and the ones I originally have. Why is that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the other HEAD you want to revert to using `git reflog` and then reset to the commit. Usually, if you didn't do anything after the pull, this would be `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`

Comment: better using `git reset --keep HEAD@{1}`

Comment: I did  'git reset --hard HEAD@{1}' and then 'git pull --rebase' but now when I do 'git status', I don't see the remote changes. It just said 'Your branch is ahead of origin/master' by 12 commits?

Comment: I would like to know how can I get 'branch is ahead of origin/master by 12 commits' when I do a 'git pull --rebase'? The whole point of doing git pull is to sync up with remote repository, right? How can I be 'ahead'?

Comment: michael: `git pull --rebase` rebases the branch onto its upstream. it will (in almost all cases) rewrite history, so the resulting repository has different commits that are not in origin

Comment: @michael: To clarify what knittl said, the 12 commits which exist only locally, and which were rebased on top of the upstream branch, are those 12 commits you're ahead by.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you're on `master` and you want to pull in remote changes to `origin/master` and rebase your work onto the "official" branch, but you made a mistake:

```
git pull origin
```

Now you've got a merge of your work and the stuff from the server; that's not what you wanted!

```
git stash save
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
git stash apply
```

Now you're back where you were before the pull, but you still want to put your changes on top of what was on the server...

```
git rebase origin/master
```

There you go, all set!